# is value attribute necessary in a react component's input?

Tags: reactjs, input

My Register component:

```
const Register = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const onNameChange = (e) => {
    setName(name = e.target.value);
  };
<form className="form" onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
    <div className="form-group">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
        name="name"
        value={name}
        onChange={onNameChange}
        required
      />
    </div>
    </form>
```

My question is what is the purpose of putting the value attribute i.e "value={name}"?

I noticed that even without writing it(the value attribute), the value(e.target.value) is taken as whatever is over the said `<input>`. It seems to me that it functions the same without the value attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a `value` attribute isn't *necessary*, but it's usually a good idea. Putting a `value` attribute makes the input *controlled*, which means that the value in the input will always exactly correspond to what's in the React state, which will make the program's logic easier to reason about.

With a controlled input, if you ever need to set the value to something other than what the user has typed in, you just need to call `setName` with the value to set, and the input will receive that new custom value.

If you use an uncontrolled component (one without a `value`), you'll probably want to [use a ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) to get the value (since having `name` / `setName` as stateful doesn't really provide a benefit anymore).